# PHP URL Rewriting and Anchor Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, anchor

i'm trying to develop with MVC, i access to the pages like that:

```
http://localhost/app/dashboard/index
```

dashboard is the controller et index is the function in the class controller dashboard.

I have a dispatcher page (index.php) which redirect and call the right files.
I have a .htaccess that rewrite urls

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ index.php?p=$1
```

So when i access to `http://localhost/app/dashboard/index`
$_GET['p'] => dashboard/index, so i can explode this array and call the classes...

That's work fine, but my problem is when i make a link suppose to launch a jquery script like that:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="myID">Item 1</a>
```

I return to the home page: `http://localhost/app`

I tried to make my link like that:

```
<a href="dashboard/index/#" data-toggle="myID">Item 1</a> or
<a href="http://localhost/app/dashboard/index/#" data-toggle="myID">Item 1</a>
```

but it didn't work!

Please help!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your first link into that. I just put a / at the beginning

```
<a href="/dashboard/index/#" data-toggle="myID">Item 1</a>
```

Comment: No, it bring me to: http://localhost/dashboard/index/# while it must be http://localhost/app/dashboard/index/#

Comment: did you simply try <a href="/app/dashboard/index/#" data-toggle="myID">Item 1</a> ??

Comment: Oups sorry, i guess what it was. Actually i forgot to write the right url for js files. So js files weren't loaded and generate error.